# Angular 7 Navigate to parent/:idChildroute/childroute, invoke data according to the route from a service

Tags: angular, angular-routing, angular7, snapshot, nested-routes

I have a component which has a scroll-able list for navigation, within that are 5 more components which show different information for the list item clicked, eg: When I click on a list item it opens a component with angular material mat-tab-group, there are 5 tabs and each has a router outlet in it. These tab components should show different parts of the data information invoked by click on the list item, more over if I paste

```
http://localhost:4200/audit/tabset/123/main
```

it should fetch the data of that route accordingly. the app routes should roughly look like this:

```
{
        path: 'audit', component: NavComponent,
        children: [
            { path: '', redirectTo: 'tabset', pathMatch: 'full' },
            {
                path: 'tabset', component: TabsetComponent,
                children: [
                    { path: '', redirectTo: 'Main', pathMatch: 'full' },
                    { path: '/:id/main', component: WorkOrderDetailComponent },
                    { path: '/:id/feed', component: FeedComponent },
                    { path: '/:id/operations', component: AuditformsmainComponent },
                    { path: '/:id/associated', component: AssociatedComponent },
                    { path: '/:id/settings', component: SettingsComponent },
                ]
            },
            { path: 'new-work-order', component: NewWorkOrderComponent },

        ]
    },
```

How do I achieve this?

Thank you in Advance

Comment: So what is your issue now? Do you know how to access route params using activatedroute?

Comment: 1- what code do I write in /:id/main etc components to make the :id work? 2- how do I capture and load the routes and the id accordingly so that the right api call is done to load the data?

Comment: Please check the answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In each of your child components, for eg: main, feed, operations etc, do this:

1) Import `ActivatedRoute` from `@angular/router`

2) Inject `ActivatedRoute` in your constructor

```
constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute){}
```

3) Make sure your component class implements `OnInit`. Then, in your `ngOnInit` method, do the following to get the id:

```
ngOnInit() {
  this.route.paramMap.subscribe(
  (params: ParamMap) => {
    this.id = params.get('id');
  }
 )
}
```

4) You will then have the id of the current product/item in `this.id`. You can then load the data using that.

Let me know if this helps :)

Comment: Thank you for the response. Can you please tell me how do I check what is the current activated component in place of main is  eg: localhost:4200/audit/tabset/W011222/main, localhost:4200/audit/tabset/W011222/feed, localhost:4200/audit/tabset/W011222/settings. I have 'main', 'feed', 'operations', 'associated', 'settings'. I want to know which one is in the current URL?

Answer (score 1):

You can use either the `ActivatedRoute` or the `ActivatedRouteSnapshot` to find the `params` of the currently activated route. You can then pass the necessary parameter to your service method to retrieve the correct information. Here is the relevant Angular documentation:

[Activated Route](https://angular.io/guide/router#activated-route)

Comment: Thank you for the response.